# Jquery tranversing DOM to find consecutives values

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors, traversal

Thanks for looking, all helpful answers are voted up.
This is my markup. I'm trying to find 2 consecutive divs `cmk1 and cmk2` with the content `RIGHT` and `HERE` in consecutive order.

- `div id 1` shouldn't match because there's a `right` but not `here`.
- `div id 3` shouldn't match because there's a `here` but no `right`.
- I'm trying to find something that looks like `div id 2` where `right` is followed by `here`. Also the text has to be exact: `<div>more than right</div>` should not match even though it contains the word `right`

What's the most efficient way to do this?

**Update: I just had a thought, I could find `each` `class=cmk1`. if it matches RIGHT, I could select its `next` (cmk2) and if it matches also, that's what I'm looking for. But how do I do this `while` loop in jquery? and most importantly how do I exit out of it?**

```
<div class="sep" id="1">
  <div class="cmk1">right</div>
  <div class="cmk2">valc</div>
  <div class="opp">vald</div>   
  <a class="go">Go</a>                  
</div>
<div class="clear">
<div class="sep" id="12">
  <div class="cmk1">RIGHT</div>
  <div class="cmk2">HERE</div>
  <div class="opp">vala</div>   
  <a class="go">Go</a>                  
</div>
<div class="clear">
<div class="sep" id="59">
  <div class="cmk1">vale</div>
  <div class="cmk2">valf</div>
  <div class="opp">here</div>   
  <a class="go">Go</a>                  
</div>
<div class="clear">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('div.sep > div').each(function() {
    if($(this).text() == 'RIGHT') {
        if($(this).next('div').text() == 'HERE') {
            alert('Values occur consecutively in div id: ' +  $(this).parent().attr('id'));
            return false;            
        }
    }
});
```

I've basically looped over all the child divs of the each .sep div and tested for the first word. If it is matched, [`next`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/next) can be used to determine if the next div contains the second word.

Comment: This goes through each one. How do I break once I've found the right one so I don't have to keep spinning my wheels now that I already found it :)

Comment: @Chris - I've edited, simply return false to break out of the loop.

Comment: Nicely done, but I think `$('.sep .cmk1')` be a more appropriate selector (less nodes selected and not tag dependent).

Comment: @Justin Johnson - I agree with you, I just did not know how much to narrow down the selection as I was unsure as to exactly what the OP was looking for (e.g. could the first word be in .cmk2 ?). Anyway, your comment is most helpful.

Comment: @karim79, What's the diff between .text() and .html() by the way? I always used .html(). Thanks for the help. Looks like this will work just fine.

Comment: @chris - html() gives you the raw html inside the specified tag, while text() will give you the combined text content all the contained HTML.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(':contains(RIGHT) :contains(HERE)')
```

Comment: Actually it has to not just contain, but the full thing be equal. For example if I'm looking for the string `partial`, `<div>partial</div>` should match true, but `<div>Some partial content</div>` should not match.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(':contains(right), :contains(here)')
    .filter( function() {
        return ( $(this).text() == 'right' && $(this).next().is(':contains(here)') ) ||
            ( $(this).text() == 'here' && $(this).prev().is(':contains(right)') );
    } );
```

The only drawback is this is case sensitive.